# How to create a 2D list in c++ not by array or vector?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to create a 2D list (n * c) (not an array/a vector), my code is as follows:

```
int n = 3;
int c = 2;
list<list<int>> S;
list<int> row;

for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
{

    row.push_back({});
}


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    
    S.push_back(row);
}
```

I don't know if the code is in the right format or not ?

How can I say that,for instance, S[k][r] = S[k-1][r] when I'm using a 2D list?

Comment: if you want random access use `std::vector` rather than `std::list` (in general use `std::vector` over `std::list`)

Comment: `std::list` has no `operator[]`, so you can't do what you're asking with that syntax. Is there a reason you've chosen to use a list? It's often the worst container to use and I am curious what benefit you feel it will give you.

Comment: `*next(*next(S.begin(),k)).begin(), r) = *next(*next(S.begin(),k-1)).begin(), r);` ... I think.  Untested.

Comment: @Eljay Beautiful or terrifying, I can't decide. :)

Comment: Have you considered using `std::deque`?

Comment: "How can I say that,for instance, S[k][r] = S[k-1][r] when I'm using a 2D list?"  You can write `operator[]` function to access the n'th object in a list using `std::next` per @Eljay but why?

Comment: Rational for not supporting `[]`: `list` is defined such that a doubly linked list is the most direct implementation. In a linked list, there only a logical connection between each stored object. To find object n+1, you must first find n, and this makes the random access, the ability to move from any element to any other element immediately, implied by operator `[]` misleading.

Comment: What is the actual high-level problem you are trying to solve?  This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Actually, I have a matrix n * c which each element of the matrix is a set of items. Let me illustrate it with an example, matrix(1, 2) must have a set like {1} and matrix(2, 3) is a set like {1, 3}. What I am considering is to define a list n*c and in each iteration I add items into a set existing in a particular element of the matrix.  I hope I could explain it well

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `list` because it doesn't have random access operators overloaded. Here's how you can do that with a vector:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct Matrix final {
 private:
  [[no_unique_address]] std::vector<T> data_;
  [[no_unique_address]] int width_;
  [[no_unique_address]] int height_;

  [[nodiscard]] int index(int const row, int const col) const noexcept {
    return width_ * row + col;
  }

 public:
  Matrix(int const width, int const height)
      : data_(width * height), width_(width), height_(height) {}

  [[nodiscard]] auto width() const noexcept { return width_; }
  [[nodiscard]] auto height() const noexcept { return height_; }

  [[nodiscard]] auto& get(int const row, int const col) noexcept {
    return data_[index(row, col)];
  }
  [[nodiscard]] auto& get(int const row, int const col) const noexcept {
    return data_[index(row, col)];
  }
};
```